# force stop when i change theme in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

I change `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">` to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">` for change the theme without change anything but when I run AVD my app force stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good you're using AppCompat or Material widgets in your activity. These widgets require particular themes (`Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.MaterialComponents` themes) in order to function. The `AppTheme` theme that Android Studio generates by default almost always is a child of a `Theme.AppCompat` theme.